# Losing products Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, products

The issue started with an **indexing error**. Error was **sqlstate 1205**.

We **restarted mysql**. We **increased timeout**. We **increased memory** because we are running a script and it **takes up a good amount of memory** but never had issues with the script before.

We now **lost 900 products**. Any ideas?

Comment: put your script here..

Comment: have you reindexed the website?